# Weird thing in python3 about shared reference

Tags: python, oop, object, python-3.x, python-internals

I run below python code, a and b will point to the same object as I know.

```
>>> a=10
>>> b=10
>>> a is b
True
```

but when I change the 10 to a bigger number such as 100000, the result is weird.

```
>>> a=100000
>>> b=100000
>>> a is b
False
```

It seems that python create two 100000 in memory.

Then I try below code:

```
>>> lst=[10,10]
>>> lst[0] is lst[1]
True

>>> lst=[100000 ,100000 ]
>>> lst[0] is lst[1]
True
```

In list the numbers (10 or 100000) are both in same object.

That's what I confused. 
Why when the number is bigger, Python create two object? and why in List, it still use one copy?

Comment: python 3.4.2  - I don't see that behavior.

Comment: @JonSurrell: I do. But that's because Python also stores literals as constants.

Comment: Bottom line: Python optimises stuff. Loads of stuff. And those optimisations can lead to Python storing just one copy of stuff. Including small integers and literals used in code. *Don't count on this behaviour in your code*, as optimisations are not part of the language definition.

Comment: Scratch that, I __do__ see it in Python3.4.2 interpreter. __Not__ in Python 3.4.2 + IPython 2.3.0

Comment: `import dis;  print(compile('[100000, 100000]', 'stdin', 'eval').co_consts)` produces `(100000,)`, meaning Python stored just the one integer to run the code with.